# Shaka player live stream does not start play-out

Tags: react-native, tizen, mpeg-dash, tizen-web-app, shaka

In our react-native-web application, running as a Tizen smart web app on Samsung smart TVs, we use ShakaPlayer 2.5.6c to play DASH live streams.

The issue is that **sometimes** the stream does not start. The DRM license is received, segments are being fetched, but somehow the player does not show any frames. The player does not log any errors.
Hours later the issue disappears. Also, the issue does not seem to affect all devices.

The live streams originate from a Halo packages that is being used for other clients as well (ExoPlayer, AVplayer & Chromecast ShakaPlayer), without any issue. We use titanium DRM license wrapping.

Below is a detailed timeline of what happens with a failing stream.
The app registers player listeners for events abrstatuschanged, adaptation, buffering, drmsessionupdate, emsg, error, expirationupdated, largegap, loading, manifestparsed, onstatechange, onstateidle, streaming, unloading, and variantchanged. Additionally, every 2.5 seconds the playhead, current manifest & buffering info is written. For each segment fetch, the response date header is shown.

We have tried with a wide range of configurations, including different values for buffering parameters, defaultPresentationDelay jumpLargeGaps and videoRobustness. All with the same result.

The timeline below shows that the same segment is fetched multiple times. It looks like the player is retrying to fetch segments, although none fail.

At first it looks like there is a DRM issue, where the player is not able to decode video chunks.
When play-out succeeds we see an extra 'expirationupdated: there is a change in the expiration times of an EME session' event right after a 'drmsessionupdate: the CDM has accepted the license response' event, which could support this theory.
However, no error is thrown by the player.

What could be the cause of this behavior? Note that the issue appear often, but not always.

```
2020-3-14 11:10:55  loading
2020-3-14 11:10:55  onstatechange                   "attach"
2020-3-14 11:10:55  onstatechange                   "media-source"
2020-3-14 11:10:55  onstatechange                   "manifest-parser"
2020-3-14 11:10:55  onstatechange                   "manifest"
2020-3-14 11:10:55  networkEngine manifest response
2020-3-14 11:10:55  manifestparsed
2020-3-14 11:10:55  onstatechange                   "drm-engine"
2020-3-14 11:10:55  onstatechange                   "load"
2020-3-14 11:10:55  buffering                       true
2020-3-14 11:10:55  streaming
2020-3-14 11:10:55  abrstatuschanged
2020-3-14 11:10:55  seekRange                       {"start":266177.98933333333,"end":266197.85233330727}
2020-3-14 11:10:55  onstateidle                     state: load
2020-3-14 11:10:56  video event: play
2020-3-14 11:10:56  network license request
2020-3-14 11:10:56  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:29 GMT"  audio1/Header.m4s 
2020-3-14 11:10:56  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  audio1/1388208802880.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:56  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:55 GMT"  video2/Header.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:56  network license                 response received
2020-3-14 11:10:56  drmsessionupdate                the CDM has accepted the license response
2020-3-14 11:10:56  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video2/1388208801440.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:57  abrstatuschanged
2020-3-14 11:10:57  adaptation                      an automatic adaptation causes the active tracks to change
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:43 GMT"  audio1/1388208981440.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:38 GMT"  video2/1388208081440.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:34 GMT"  audio1/1388208261440.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:56 GMT"  video3/Header.m4s
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208081440.m4s    MISS
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208081440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208081440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:57  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208081440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  current status                  player.isBuffering(): true; player.isInProgress(): false
2020-3-14 11:10:58  current manifest info           delay: 10s; maxSegmentDuration: 2.25s; seekRange: [2020-3-14 11:10:25 - 2020-3-14 11:10:45]; usingPresentationStartTime: false;
2020-3-14 11:10:58  live presentationStartTime      2020-3-11 09:14:05
2020-3-14 11:10:58  live playhead time              2020-3-14 11:10:34
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208081440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208081440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine manifest response
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:33 GMT"  audio1/1388208082880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:58  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:34 GMT"  audio1/1388208261440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:59  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208081440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:59  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:37 GMT"  audio1/1388208441920.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:10:59  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  video3/1388208261440.m4s    MISS
2020-3-14 11:10:59  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:49 GMT"  video3/1388208441440.m4s    MISS
2020-3-14 11:10:59  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:51 GMT"  video3/1388208621440.m4s    MISS
2020-3-14 11:10:59  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:53 GMT"  video3/1388208801440.m4s    MISS
2020-3-14 11:11:00  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:39 GMT"  audio1/1388208622400.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:00  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:41 GMT"  audio1/1388208802880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:00  buffering                       false
2020-3-14 11:11:00  current status                  player.isBuffering(): false; player.isInProgress(): false
2020-3-14 11:11:00  current manifest info           delay: 10s; maxSegmentDuration: 2.25s; seekRange: [2020-3-14 11:10:28 - 2020-3-14 11:10:48]; usingPresentationStartTime: false; 
2020-3-14 11:11:00  live presentationStartTime      2020-3-11 09:14:05
2020-3-14 11:11:00  live playhead time              2020-3-14 11:10:34
2020-3-14 11:11:00  buffered time                   [2020-3-14 11:10:31 to 2020-3-14 11:10:40]
2020-3-14 11:11:01  networkEngine manifest response
2020-3-14 11:11:03  current status                  player.isBuffering(): false; player.isInProgress(): false
2020-3-14 11:11:03  current manifest info           delay: 10s; maxSegmentDuration: 2.25s; seekRange: [2020-3-14 11:10:30 - 2020-3-14 11:10:50]; usingPresentationStartTime: false; 
2020-3-14 11:11:03  live presentationStartTime      2020-3-11 09:14:05
2020-3-14 11:11:03  live playhead time              2020-3-14 11:10:34
2020-3-14 11:11:03  buffered time                   [2020-3-14 11:10:31 to 2020-3-14 11:10:40]
2020-3-14 11:11:04  networkEngine manifest response
2020-3-14 11:11:05  current status                  player.isBuffering(): false; player.isInProgress(): false
2020-3-14 11:11:05  current manifest info           delay: 10s; maxSegmentDuration: 2.25s; seekRange: [2020-3-14 11:10:33 - 2020-3-14 11:10:53]; usingPresentationStartTime: false; 
2020-3-14 11:11:05  live presentationStartTime      2020-3-11 09:14:05
2020-3-14 11:11:05  live playhead time              2020-3-14 11:10:34
2020-3-14 11:11:05  buffered time                   [2020-3-14 11:10:31 to 2020-3-14 11:10:40]
2020-3-14 11:11:07  adaptation                      an automatic adaptation causes the active tracks to change
2020-3-14 11:11:07  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:11:04 GMT"  video3/1388208981440.m4s    MISS
2020-3-14 11:11:07  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:43 GMT"  audio1/1388208981440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:07  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:45 GMT"  audio1/1388209161920.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:07  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:29 GMT"  video7/Header.m4s           HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:07  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:47 GMT"  audio1/1388209342400.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:07  networkEngine manifest response
2020-3-14 11:11:08  current status                  player.isBuffering(): false; player.isInProgress(): false
2020-3-14 11:11:08  current manifest info           delay: 10s; maxSegmentDuration: 2.25s; seekRange: [2020-3-14 11:10:35 - 2020-3-14 11:10:55]; usingPresentationStartTime: false; 
2020-3-14 11:11:08  live presentationStartTime      2020-3-11 09:14:05
2020-3-14 11:11:08  live playhead time              2020-3-14 11:10:39
2020-3-14 11:11:08  buffered time                   [2020-3-14 11:10:31 to 2020-3-14 11:10:42]
2020-3-14 11:11:08  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:45 GMT"  video7/1388209161440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:09  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:47 GMT"  video7/1388209341440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:10  current status                  player.isBuffering(): false; player.isInProgress(): false
2020-3-14 11:11:10  current manifest info           delay: 10s; maxSegmentDuration: 2.25s; seekRange: [2020-3-14 11:10:38 - 2020-3-14 11:10:58]; usingPresentationStartTime: false; 
2020-3-14 11:11:10  live presentationStartTime      2020-3-11 09:14:05
2020-3-14 11:11:10  live playhead time              2020-3-14 11:10:40
2020-3-14 11:11:10  buffered time                   [2020-3-14 11:10:31 to 2020-3-14 11:10:46]
2020-3-14 11:11:11  networkEngine manifest response
2020-3-14 11:11:12  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:49 GMT"  audio1/1388209522880.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:12  networkEngine segment           "date":"Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:51 GMT"  audio1/1388209701440.m4s    HIT
2020-3-14 11:11:13  current status                  player.isBuffering(): false; player.isInProgress(): false
2020-3-14 11:11:13  current manifest info           delay: 10s; maxSegmentDuration: 2.25s; seekRange: [2020-3-14 11:10:40 - 2020-3-14 11:11:00]; usingPresentationStartTime: false; 
2020-3-14 11:11:13  live presentationStartTime      2020-3-11 09:14:05
2020-3-14 11:11:13  live playhead time              2020-3-14 11:10:45
2020-3-14 11:11:13  buffered time                   [2020-3-14 11:10:31 to 2020-3-14 11:10:46]
```

Comment: Any update on this? I am also facing a similar issue.

Comment: The solution here was to switch to PlayReady DRM. Widevine was not stable enough.